# Plotting more than one data frame is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these data frames that I got from a CSV file, they are saved in variables called df1 and df2.

`df1 = df[df['player'] == 'p1']`

`df2 = df[df['player'] == 'p2']`

player | x | y
p1     | 1 | 3
p1     | 2 | 4
p1     | 3 | 5

player | x | y
p2     | 1 | 6
p2     | 2 | 7
p2     | 3 | 8

I want to plot their data as two separate line, what I did was the following:

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame({'p1': df1['y'], 'p2':df2['y']}, index=[1,2,3])
lines = df_final .plot.line()
```

But this did not work, it gave me an empty axis and with both x and y has the same value of y.
I looked for many posts on the internet and tried many stuff (for example appending them and such).
Why is that wrong?

Thank you

Comment: using another library for the plot is a option?

Comment: In the homework they specified only pandas, so apparently not.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the plotting you want?

Comment: And show us your full code, cause I used the same code as you and it works for me! Maybe it's a problem of some variables?

Comment: @YounessSaadna, I fixed it, apparently it was a variable thing as you mentioned. it's funny how very small things sometimes give you mental breakdown :/

Comment: It happens sometimes ...